# Less cumbersome notation for jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, determinant

Is there a less cumbersome notation for the Jacobian of some multivariate functions? For instance, suppose I have $n$ multivariate functions of $n$ variables, $u_1(x_1,...,x_n),...,u_n(x_1,...,x_n)$. The partial derivative notations that can be used are

$$\frac{\partial u_k}{\partial x_j} \equiv u_{k_{x_j}}$$

both of which are rather cumbersome when there are $n^2$ of them to write. Is there a more compact notation for the Jacobian or is this all we've got?

Comment: Some people write the Jacobian as $\frac{\partial \mathbf u}{\partial \mathbf x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sometimes write $\mathbf{J}f(x)$ and leave it at that. That way I view the Jacobian as not just an object, but a sort of operator, akin to the derivative.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to write a proof that $$\frac{\partial(u_1,...,u_n)}{\partial(x_1,...,x_n)} = \frac{1}{\frac{\partial(x_1,...,x_n)}{\partial(u_1,...,u_n)}}$$

and so it's essential that I'm able to read off the elements of the matrix. Maybe I'm looking for a different notation for the partial derivative?

Comment: @Ed_4434 I often write partials like $\partial_i f_j$ or $\partial_{i_1\cdots i_k} f_j$ for the multiple partial derivative.  That's about the shortest I can think to express a partial derivative.

Comment: Then maybe you can write $(\mathbf{J}f(x))_{i, j}$ for each entry. Derivative of function i with respect to variable j.

Comment: Cool, thanks to both of you :)

Comment: @SeanRoberson. It is advisable to write $(\mathbf{J}f(x))_{i j} $ instead of $(\mathbf{J}f(x))_{i, j}$. You know, there is a quite widespread convention in whhich a comma before the index means a further derivative.